# Push notification showing only app logo without any text

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Push notification showing only app logo without any text.The words only appear when there is an existing notification. This problem is observed only in Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (Kitkat 4.4.2) device. Please help

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle notiStyle1 = null;
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle2 = null;       

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.custom_notification);          
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notiStyle1 = new 
                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();          

            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_small);
        }
        else
        {
            notiStyle2 = new 
                    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();

            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        notificationIndex    = EntraderApplication.getApplication()
                .getNOTIFICATION_ID();

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        System.out.println("Status : " + status + ", message : " + message
                + ", content : " + content);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("1") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("2")
                || status.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            try {

                    Log.e("DONT MOVE------>", "in else part");
                    TradeEntry entry = new ObjectMapper().readValue(content,
                            TradeEntry.class);
                    entry.toString();                   

                    bundle.putSerializable(
                            CustomerHomeFragment.CustomerHomeFragment_data, entry);
                    bundle.putString(
                            CustomerHomeFragment.CustomerHomeFragment_data_type,
                            status);

                    bundle.putInt(Pref_Noti_Clicked, msg_counter);
                    //bundle.put
                //  notificationIntent.putExtra(Pref_Noti_Clicked, msg_counter);
                    System.out.println("Added type : "+ status);
                    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationIndex,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
        {
            mBuilder.setStyle(notiStyle1);
        }
        else
        {
            mBuilder.setStyle(notiStyle2);
        }       


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
        if (EntraderApplication.getApplication().getSharePreference()
                .getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.pref_vibration), true)) {
            mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 });
        }


        if (EntraderApplication
                .getApplication()
                .getSharePreference()
                .getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.pref_notification), true)) {
            mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        }


        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
        mBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationIndex, notification);
```

Comment: https://api.asm.skype.com/s/i?0-weu-d4-5cc78c58b17a3456e60a1645292d03cb -  screenshot of above issue

Comment: You should provide a code snippet. 
And i can't view this link because is not allowed in my company.

Comment: please copy the code creating the notification to show. i think probably you're trying to use a deprecated code.

Answer (score 0):

I would say make the code more modular and organized. Its difficult to catch the issue just by looking at the code. It seems you have added but they are not in proper order (maybe).

Have methods such as `sendNotification` inside `onHandleIntent` that would be triggered as soon as a notification is received.. Here is an example:

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                sendNotification(extras.toString());

                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.checkmark)
                        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Hope this Helps!!